# multiple functions onclick addeventlistener

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that works when triggered by an onclick *for example:* onClick="change('imgA');"

```
function change(v) {
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    if (v == "imgA") {
        target.className = "cast1";
    } else if (v == "imgB") {
        target.className = "cast2";
    } else if (v == "imgC") {
        target.className = "cast3";
    } else if (v == "imgD") {
        target.className = "cast4";
    } else {
        target.className = "chart";
    }
}
```

as soon as this result is stored to the id 'target', How do I perform this same function again but with different classNames ('bio1' instead of 'cast1', etc).  then save the results to a different id?

Everytime I've tried hasn't worked to this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
function change(v, id) {
  var areas;
  if( id == 'target' ) {
    areas = 'cast';
  } else {
    areas = 'bio';
  }
  var target = document.getElementById(id);
  if (v == "imgA") {target.className = areas+"1";}
  else if (v == "imgB") {target.className = areas+"2";}
  else if (v == "imgC") {target.className = areas+"3";}
  else if (v == "imgD") {target.className = areas+"4";}
  else {target.className = "chart";}
}
```

Comment: can you please explain the areas+"1", etc.

Comment: I'm understanding the code now, thanks.  But when I apply the code, the onclick('target') isn't triggering the code.